# Setting the samesite cookie attrbute using resteasy

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, samesite

I am working on a quarkus project.  I have built a REST API using RestEasy. I am setting a cookie back to the caller of this API like

```
return Response.ok("Alice").cookie(new NewCookie("jwt", newJwtCookie)).build();
```

I would like to set the samesite attribute as Strict.  NewCookie doesnt yet support this. Is there some where to do this in Quarkus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a manual option..

```java
return Response.ok("Alice").header("Set-Cookie", "jwt="+newJwtCookie+"; SameSite=strict").build();
```

there is also a related flag `quarkus.http.same-site-cookie.jwt.value=Strict` in application.properties.

Comment: This is a manual option..
`return Response.ok("Alice").header("Set-Cookie", "jwt="+newJwtCookie+"; SameSite=strict").build();`